# What is the standard 120V light bulb screw base in the US?

Tags: electrical, lighting, bulb

I know that standard incandescent bulbs in the US use Edison screw bases, but I'm not sure which designation / number is the one which is used for prolific non-candelabra 120 volt fixtures.

Comment: The US uses a 120V system, not 110.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The US 120 volt screw base is an E26. The 'E' indicates an Edison screw base and 26 is the diameter in millimeters.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edison_screw#Types) *([footnote 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edison_screw#cite_note-3))*

> In 120-volt North America and 100-volt Japan, the standard size for general-purpose lamps is E26

Answer (score 5):

For those who like to do things the hard way, it is also 7004-21A-2 (From IEC Standard sheet 60061-1 (of course)

The E26 is the 'standard' for 110 Volt systems and the E27 is the standard for 220 Volt systems. (The E27 being IEC 7004-21)

Comment: Really? There's only 1mm difference in diameter? That may well be the explanation for why standard light bulbs sold in the U.S, for several years now, have often had such a miserable, "tight" fit in lampholders!

Comment: In the UK, they (E27, E14) are often just called ES (Edison Screw) or SES (Small Edison Screw) - in contrast to BC (Bayonet Cap) and SBC (Small Bayonet Cap).

Comment: @kreemoweet: I'd guess E26 is 1" and E27 is 1 1/16". *"The metric system is the tool of the devil! My car gets forty rods to the hogshead and that's the way I likes it."* - Thomas Edison :-).

Comment: Furlongs per fortnight as always been my unit speed. I did learn recently about the unit of property measure, the 'chain' there being 10 square chains in an acre. (Which makes each chain a furlong, of course)